# Configuring Kerberos krb5.conf file to handle primary and a secondary 'cloned' domain

Tags: networking, domain, kerberos

*(Obligatory newbie prefix: never played much with Kerberos so treat me gently here!)*

We have two domains `foo.local` and `.test`.

`.test` was cloned from `foo.local` and, once logged on to a server inside `.test` the domain thinks it **is** the `foo.local` domain.

e.g. `myserver.foo.local` has an IP address of **10.250.20.10** and `myserver.test` has an IP address of **10.*253*.20.10** when inside the `foo.local` domain, but sees itself as **10.250.20.10** when inside the `.test` domain.

In addition `myserver.foo.local` can reach out to `myserver.test` but the opposite is not true.

Also, `myserver.foo.local` when reaching out to `myothersever.foo.local` does indeed hit a server that is inside the `foo.local` domain, however when `myserver.test` connects to `myotherserver.foo.local` then it remains stuck inside the `.test` domain.

This all said, here's my `/etc/krb5.conf` file (which I'm more than happy to learn is badly configured):

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = FOO.LOCAL

[realms]
    FOO.LOCAL = {
        kdc = foo-dc01.foo.local
    }

    TEST = {
        kdc = foo-dc02.test
    }
```

Life is good when connecting to servers inside `foo.local` and indeed my `kinit` works a treat. `Test` not so much.

```
myLogin$ kinit -V  mylogin@test
mylogin@test's password: 
kinit: krb5_get_init_creds: unable to reach any KDC in realm test, tried 0 KDCs
```

So, questions:

1) What steps am I missing to authenticate against the test domain - how do I configure `kinit` to use the `foo-dc02.test` domain server to authenticate (or even, do I given that my Windows LoginId and password are the same)?

2) Once done, how do I ensure that when connecting to `myserver.test` it uses the token derived from the `kinit mylogin@test` when attempting a connection?

**System Info:** All AD servers are Windows, right now my POC tests are from my MacBook but clients running on Windows, Macs and Linux will all need to work eventually.

Comment: All the servers are virtual, we copied all the servers and fired them up inside different physical hosts and provided routing to go from .foo.local to .test. My question doesn't so much pertain to the cloning but "how do we get tokens from the .test domain"

Comment: I made the above comment because a user asked how the environments were cloned. Sadly that person then subsequently deleted their question thus leading mine dangling. Keeping it there to provide context.

Answer (score 0):

> e.g. myserver.foo.local has an IP address of 10.250.20.10 and myserver.test has an IP address of 10.253.20.10 when inside the foo.local domain, but sees itself as 10.250.20.10 when inside the  .test domain.

Addressing is generally irrelevant to Kerberos, as long as clients are able to resolve the DNS names and speak to the servers (send/receive IP packets).

> myLogin$ kinit -V  mylogin@test
>   mylogin@test's password:
>   kinit: krb5_get_init_creds: unable to reach any KDC in realm test, **tried 0 KDCs**

You are trying to authenticate to the `test` realm. To Kerberos, this is *not* the same as the `TEST` realm which you have in krb5.conf – unlike DNS domains or AD domains, a Kerberos realm name is case-sensitive.

Because the lowercase `test` realm is not in [realms] in your krb5.conf, *kinit* uses other methods to find the KDC server – it looks for DNS SRV `_kerberos._udp.<realm>` records after translating the realm back to a DNS domain.

For example, when you're authenticating against `…@test` or `…@TEST` and there is no matching [realms] subsection, you will need SRV records at `_kerberos._udp.test` at minimum. (Active Directory *should* add these automatically.)

Either use `kinit mylogin@TEST` with the correct case, or adjust the [realms] configuration, or ensure that there are SRV records in your `test` DNS domain pointing to the domain controller.

(Additionally: If you choose to use the lowercase `kinit mylogin@test`, Active Directory KDCs *will* recognize the lowercase form but the returned tickets have the realm in canonical uppercase anyway and most kinit versions will reject the mismatching response. You will allow canonicalization using `kinit -C`.)

If your client software is MIT Krb5, use `export KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stderr` to obtain more information about what exactly it is doing. (macOS probably uses Heimdal though.)

> 2) Once done, how do I ensure that when connecting to myserver.test it uses the token derived from the kinit mylogin@test when attempting a connection?

Check what credential cache type is being used (as shown by `klist` in "Ticket cache" or set in the $KRB5CCNAME environment variable).

The traditional "FILE:" credential cache can only have tickets for one client principal in the first place. If you kinit as mylogin@TEST, you will *always* be using tickets for mylogin@TEST. In this case you will have to manually switch between different caches, by setting $KRB5CCNAME to different paths.

```
$ export KRB5CCNAME="FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000_prod" && kinit user@PROD && klist
$ export KRB5CCNAME="FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000_test" && kinit user@TEST && klist

$ kset() { export KRB5CCNAME="FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_$(id -u)_$1"; }
$ kset prod && kinit user@PROD && klist
```

When using MIT Krb5, the "DIR:" and (on Linux) "KEYRING:" credential caches support multiple client principals at once. You can simply kinit multiple times, then switch the 'active' principal using `kswitch` or even define custom rules in the `~/.k5identity` file (man 5 k5identity).

Unfortunately, some important programs (such as smbclient or Apache Directory Studio) do not understand "DIR:" caches yet (or anything except FILE: actually).

When using macOS, the same as above applies, but I believe the default credential cache type is "KCM:" which can *probably* hold multiple client principals. Or maybe not ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Windows works differently; the ticket cache is tightly bound to your login session and (again) only supports one client principal. To start programs as another principal without a full logout/login, use `runas /netonly`:

```
runas /netonly /user:mylogin@test cmd
```

Comment: Thanks for the post - fighting fires right now so will have to look later.